# My box-bottom shadow is not working when scrolled down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to add a box-bottom shadow to the fixed header when scroll down. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
           </button>
            <a href="http://www.aspentech.com/" class="navbar-brand">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo@2x.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="login">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active">
                  <a id="loginLink" href="#" class="navbar-text navbar-icon-link">
                  <span class="navbar-profile-icon center-block"></span>Hello, Sijie!</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav subnav-nav">
                <li class="subnav">
                  <span class="navbar-text subnav-link" id="subnav-link-1"><a class="sub" href="index.html">aspenOne Update Center</a></span>
                </li>
                <li class="subnav">
                  <span class="navbar-text subnav-link activated" id="subnav-link-2"><a class="sub activated" href="download center.html">aspenOne Download Center</a></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
     </nav>
```

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/dojcr29w/
Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting from Chrome console. [image]

Comment: Please create a working fiddle with content so that it is scrollable.

Comment: I added the rest of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In css instead of

```
.navbar-default .active {
      box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    }
```

do it

```
.active {
      box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
```

Comment: I did that, still not working, in my chrome console, it is telling me the $ in the js file is not defined.

Comment: in jsfiddle you should choose jquery library.. currently you have pure js.. you can see select at top left

Comment: I don't know which jquery library to choose.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to target your `.navbar-default` that has `.active` class with CSS, you have to do it like this :

```
.navbar-default.active {}
```

Now, your CSS should look like this, after adding `position:fixed;`

```
.navbar-default.active {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position:fixed;
}
```

See [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky3s6fhh/)

Just to prevent your nav from jumping each time the fixed position is enabled/disabled, I just add `>=` in the if statement :

```
if (scroll >= 0) {
    $(".navbar-default").addClass("active");
} else {
    $(".navbar-default").removeClass("active");
}
```

---

As mentioned by Sijie Wang, to prevent errors in console, you have to include a jQuery library to your fiddle.